# Get files from ftp with same name

Tags: linux, ftp, filenames

I've been asked to download a directory from an ftp server.

The problem is that directories contain files with the same name. At first I immediatly thought this was a windows/unix thing and lower/uppercase was the cause of this, but it wasn't: see here an ftp ls of the server:

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command succeeded xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53930
150 Opening data connection for LIST
drwxr-x--- 1 -2 6240            0 Jul 30  2010 WID
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240       405233 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 05.Overeenkomsten.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        25757 Aug 18  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 05.Overeenkomsten.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240         5641 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 07.Veiligheidsbrochure.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240         6242 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 08.Huisvestingsverklaring.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        10548 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 09.Inschrijving gemeente.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        30901 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 10.Instroomtabel.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        45206 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 11.Ziektekostenverzekering.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        20625 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 14.Academy overeenkomst.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        39641 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 16.Eigenschappen en kwalificaties.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        22230 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 17.Checklist.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        41730 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 18.Zorgtoeslag.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240       356980 Sep 21  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 18.Zorgtoeslag.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        15690 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 99.Overige bijlagen.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        71909 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 99.Overige bijlagen.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        12914 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 99.Overige bijlagen.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 55247 6240        13530 Jul 30  2010 5639 - Daniel  - 99.Overige bijlagen.pdf
226 LIST successful.
ftp>
```

How is this possible? maybe some sort of virtual ftp server which combines directories?

And more importantly how do I download these? There are too many files to edit manually. Is it possible to add a number to the filename if it already exists?

Comment: IMPOSSIBRU! http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/105/0/9/impossibru__by_marcus_colter-d4w88jh.png

Comment: my face exactly, but that's what I'm seeing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some more access to the server we found out it was a webdav share. Which made multiple files with the same name seem less impossible.

We used a windows machine to rename duplicate files, that fixed it for us :)